# how to change Map<String,String> to Map<String,Ratio> with ratio being x/y

Tags: java, regex, generics, dictionary, integer-arithmetic

I have a String of mixed data, some words and numbers.  The numbers are either whole integers, ratios of integers, or a percent sign in front of a whole integer.  I'm trying to store this information in a Map (could be another type of object, if that makes sense) for the duration of the run of the program (not to a database).  Leaving aside the percent sign, the rest of the data is parsed ok.  I can always expect the data to be in this exact form of variables with colons.

Correct output (tabs gives funny indent):

```
AB: 272/272  CD: 204/529  EFGH: 105 HIJKL: 105  MN: 0 OPQ: 0%
AB      272/272
HIJKL       105
CD      204/529
MN      0
EFGH        105
OPQ     0%
-----------
AB      272/272
CD      204/529
HIJKL       105/1
MN      0/1
EFGH        105/1
OPQ     0/1
```

The first print is with `Map<String,String>`, the second is with `Map<String,Ratio>`.  If there's a better choice than my homemade ratio, I'll gladly use that.

clumsy code, yes, overusing static, just meant to be easy to copy/paste:

```
package regex;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import static java.lang.System.out;

class Ratio {

    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    private Ratio() {
    }

    public Ratio(int numerator, int denominator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    public int getNumerator() {
        return numerator;
    }

    public int getDenominator() {
        return denominator;
    }

    public String toString() {


        return numerator + "/" + denominator;
    }
}

public class Ratios {

    private static String line = "AB: 272/272  CD: 204/529  EFGH: 105 HIJKL: 105  MN: 0 OPQ: 0%";
    private static Map<String, String> rawMapStringToString = new HashMap<>();
    private static Map<String, Ratio> mapStringToRatio = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        out.println(line);
        populateMap();
        printMap(rawMapStringToString);
        out.println("-----------");
        ratios();
        printMap(mapStringToRatio);
    }

    private static void populateMap() {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+): +(\\S+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            rawMapStringToString.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
        }
    }

    private static void printMap(Map<?, ?> m) {
        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> e : m.entrySet()) {
            String key = e.getKey().toString();
            String val = e.getValue().toString();
            out.println(key + "\t\t" + val);
        }
    }

    private static void ratios() {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)/(\\d+)");
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)");
        Matcher m2;
        int num, den;
        Ratio ratio = null;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : rawMapStringToString.entrySet()) {
            ratio = null;
            num = 0;
            den = 1;
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(e.getValue());
            while (matcher.find()) {
                num = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
                den = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
                ratio = new Ratio(num, den);
            }
            if (ratio == null) {
                m2 = p2.matcher(e.getValue());
                while (m2.find()) {
                    num = Integer.parseInt(m2.group());
                    den = 1;
                    ratio = new Ratio(num, den);
                }
            }
            mapStringToRatio.put(e.getKey(), ratio);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just looking for a good way to store this data.  Of course, the percent can be represented as a ratio, x/y, just change the denominator to 100.  Leaving that aside for now, is a Map a good choice?

The `ratios` method, and overall regex, seems fragile, awkward, and difficult (for me) to follow, and yet I'm unsure how to improve the code.  Keeping the `Ratio` class pretty much untouched, how can I improve the `ratios` method, which populates the `mapStringToRatio`?

Answer (score 1):

What you're going to do with the data is very important to help decide what kind of data structure to store it into. If you're just printing them, storing them would be a waste of time. But I'm pretty sure you're not just printing this data right?

A Map is fine as long as your keys don't repeat. Otherwise you'll be replacing existing values with new ones that have the same key. If you don't think that's a problem, than you can keep the Map.

One other possible solution is to store the key inside the Ratio itself. So your Ratio object would have a "name" member and then you can store your data in a List of Ratios.

I liked your Ratio object and I think there's not much more to add (or remove) from it. I do agree that Regexp are complex and hard to read and understand what the code is doing. But I also think that the solution you gave is nice and clean. To make the code simpler and more readable you could use a Pattern with named groups and put everything in one pattern only. I wrote the following code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<key>\\w+)\\s*:\\s*(?<numerator>\\d+)/*(?<denominator>\\d*)%*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(INPUT);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Key: %s, Numerator: %s, Denominator: %s\n",
        matcher.group("key"), 
        matcher.group("numerator"), 
        matcher.group("denominator"));
}
```

If a group doesn't exist it will return an empty String. That way you can test it using isEmpty:

```
matcher.group("denominator").isEmpty()
```

One thing I would do is to take this logic into a separate class that would be easier to test. Have everything as static variables running from a main method is not recommended.

If you're looking for a different solution than Regexp you could use a [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to separate them using the space/tab. And then break the string using split for a colon. Then check for % or / in the right string and process them differently.

Something like:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input);
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String [] nameValuePair = tokenizer.nextToken().split(":");
    if (nameValuePair[1].contains("/")) {
        // process ratio here
    } else if (nameValurPair[1].contains("%")) {
        // Process percentage here
    } else {
        // Process String here
    }
}
```

The disadvantage of this code is that if you add new types for values you'll end up with long if/else chain. It is also harder to test since you'll have many different branches in it. If you don't plan to add new value types then that would be fine.

If you plan to expand this a lot I would go with a more abstract approach, creating a RatioProcessor interface and different implementations for it like PercentageRatioProcessor and DivisionRatioProcessor. This interface would have a "canProcess" method and a "process" method that would return a boolean and a Ratio respectively. The boolean indicating if that's the correct processor to use and the object is the processed Ratio.

Comment: thank you for the feedback.  Yes, I will be using the data, pardon if that wasn't clear.  It's static just as sample code.  I was more looking at the repeated regex and thinking there might be some way to do that in one step with one regex.  However, maybe entails some huge, indecipherable (well, for me) regex which is difficult to maintain.  It's that `if (ratio == null)` line which just seems awkward or convoluted somehow.

Comment: I added to my answer a solution with one regexp using named groups. That makes it readable and cleaner! I hope that helps!

Comment: took me a while to figure out that `matcher = pattern.matcher()` is a sort of if statement.  I added my own answer of sorts below.

Answer (score 0):

This works. I'm not quite sure it's correct, but I don't think it's too bad.

results:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/StackOverflow$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/StackOverflow$ java -jar dist/StackOverflow.jar 
AB      272/272
CD      204/529
HIJKL       105/1
MN      0/1
EFGH        105/1
OPQ     0/100
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/StackOverflow$
```

code:

```
package ratios;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Ratios {

    private String input = "AB: 272/272  CD: 204/529  EFGH: 105 HIJKL: 105  MN: 0 OPQ: 0%";
    private Map<String, String> strings = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, Ratio> stringsToRatios = new HashMap<>();

    public Ratios() {
        firstMap();
        secondMap();
        printMap(stringsToRatios);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Ratios();
    }

    private void secondMap() {
        Pattern fraction = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)/(\\d+)");
        Pattern whole = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
        Pattern percent = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)%");
        Matcher matcher;
        int num, den;
        Ratio ratio = null;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : strings.entrySet()) {

            matcher = whole.matcher(e.getValue());
            while (matcher.find()) {
                num = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
                den = 1;
                ratio = new Ratio(num, den);
            }

            matcher = fraction.matcher(e.getValue());
            while (matcher.find()) {
                num = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
                den = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
                ratio = new Ratio(num, den);
            }


            matcher = percent.matcher(e.getValue());
            while (matcher.find()) {
                num = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
                den = 100;
                ratio = new Ratio(num, den);
            }

            stringsToRatios.put(e.getKey(), ratio);
        }
    }

    private void firstMap() {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+): +(\\S+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            strings.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
        }
    }

    private void printMap(Map<?, ?> m) {
        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> e : m.entrySet()) {
            String key = e.getKey().toString();
            String val = e.getValue().toString();
            out.println(key + "\t\t" + val);
        }
    }
}
```